# Putting Ubuntu on an SSD connected via USB:

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd

I am putting together a server, and I want to put Ubuntu on the boot drive. I have a SATA->USB converter which I can connect the server's disk directly to my Mac laptop. How can I put Ubuntu directly on the disc? Will using the procedure on http://www.pendrivelinux.com work?

I have formatted the drive in ExFAT format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you put the Ubuntu installer either on a pendrive or CD, and run the installer on your Mac with the boot drive plugged in. Point the install directory for Ubuntu not towards the Mac's hard drive (most likely the default setting), but rather on the boot drive instead.

Place the drive (with Ubuntu installed) inside the server, and it should startup. You will have to install drivers and stuff afterwards.

However, why do you want to do this? Build your server and install Ubuntu directly on the server by USB or CD, rather than using your Mac to install the files on the boot drive.